# "Angels fall, they are towers": what is "towers" here? Froma poem by G.M.Hopkins

Tags: meaning, poetry

From a poem of G. M. Hopkins titled "[The Shepherd’s brow, fronting forked lightning, owns](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Shepherd%E2%80%99s_brow,_fronting_forked_lightning,_owns)":

> THE SHEPHERD’S brow, fronting forked lightning, owns
>
> The horror and the havoc and the glory
>
> Of it. Angels fall, they are **towers**, from heaven—a story
>
> Of just, majestical, and giant groans.

What does "towers" mean here? Angels are supposed to be beings with wings. Doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of *towers* here is a [metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor):

> A metaphor is a figure of speech that describes a subject by asserting that it is, on some point of comparison, the same as another otherwise unrelated object... In simpler terms, a metaphor compares two objects or things without using the words "like" or "as".

Thus, the angels are being *compared to* towers in some respect. This metaphor appears to align with a metaphor for humanity two lines later:

> ...Angels fall, **they are towers**, from heaven—a story
>
> Of just, majestical, and giant groans.
>
> But **man — we, scaffold of score brittle bones**...

Where humans are compared to brittle scaffolding, angels are compared to towers.

Comment: But that would be literary interpretation.

Comment: @Kris The main point of my answer should be "the use of *towers* here is an instance of metaphor" (which I hope you won't find subjective); everything else was meant to be supporting evidence. I'll refactor my answer to be less subjective.

Comment: Sounds good. The angels are towers in the sense of being "monumental". Their fall is earth-shattering. I'd never read any G.M.Hopkins poems before CopperKettle's questions and I have to say they are incredibly obscure.

Comment: Thanks, apsillers! Now I see, it's the "towers - scaffold" comparison. "We are mere bones' scaffolding compared to these towers, and their fall overshadows our misfortunes". Didn't caught that. His poems are obscure but a pleasure to read once understood.